# how to change 'return' button in keyboard?

Tags: react-native

How can I change the return button to some other native buttons ios has?

Now it shows the grey `return` button and instead I want it to be blue with some other text like the example below:

EXAMPLE:

[image]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update for 2019 - RN 0.57 changed the key from "Go" to "go"**

you should use **returnKeyType** property to determine how the return key should look

Example:

```
 <TextInput style={{height:40}} 
       placeholder="Input"
       placeholderTextColor="#DCDCDC"
       returnKeyType="go"
 />
```

Answer (score 7):

**Update 2019:** Using version `react-native 0.57` the accepted answer is no longer valid as "Go" is not one of the accepted values, use "go" without capitalisation instead

Actual `react-native 0.57` contract states the following enums:

```
    /**
     * enum('default', 'go', 'google', 'join', 'next', 'route', 'search', 'send', 'yahoo', 'done', 'emergency-call')
     * Determines how the return key should look.
     */
    returnKeyType?: ReturnKeyTypeOptions;
```